# Infinite scrolling of WP categories doesn't load all elements

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I set up a site for a photographer & she wanted to use her blog categories as her portfolio, which works fine, except for the fact that the infinite scrolling feature I'm using won't load all of the content for the excerpts.

The two items that it omits are the post thumbnail (image) and the horizontal row serving as a separator between the posts.

Any insight on this is appreciated - I'm using Paul Irish's infinite scroll plugin & the category excerpts are being called like so:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section id="content" role="main">
<header class="header">
<h1 class="entry-title"><!-- <?php _e( 'Category Archives: ', 'themename' ); ?> --> <?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
<?php if ( '' != category_description() ) echo apply_filters( 'archive_meta', '<div class="archive-meta">' . category_description() . '</div>' ); ?>
</header>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?><div class="cat-thumbs align-right"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
<?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?>
<hr />
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'nav', 'below' ); ?>
</section>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is the entry template:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<header>
<?php if ( is_singular() ) { echo '<h1 class="entry-title">'; } else { echo '<h2 class="entry-title">'; } ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a><?php if ( is_singular() ) { echo '</h1>'; } else { echo '</h2>'; } ?><?php edit_post_link(); ?>
<?php if ( !is_search() ) get_template_part( 'entry', 'meta' ); ?>
</header>
<?php get_template_part( 'entry', ( is_archive() || is_search() ? 'summary' : 'content' ) ); ?>
<?php if ( !is_search() ) get_template_part( 'entry-footer' ); ?>
</article>
```

For reference, this is how I'm calling the excerpts for the blog, which have no issue:

```
<section class="entry-content">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><div class="cat-thumbs align-right"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div></a>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<em><p>
<?php comments_number( '0 comments', '1 comment', '% comments' ); ?>.
</p></em>
<div class="entry-links"><?php wp_link_pages(); ?></div>
</section>
<hr />
```

[Link to example](http://www.shannonmichelphotography.com/category/newborn/)

Comment: @leftside, I added some more code for reference.

Comment: Any chance you can link the page? If that's not possible I would say check the response of the AJAX request first to see where the problem occurs. (either in the response, or when the posts are added to the list). That narrows the possibilities a little, could still be hard to find, I see no immediate error in your code.

Comment: @FlorianRachor, link added

Comment: the images that are there already: are they inserted in the post or are they featured images?

Comment: @leftside, those are the featured images, or the_post_thumbnail.  I also noticed that, prior to making an adjustment, some items that were appended using jQuery were also not making it through with the infinite scroll on the blog posts, which I resolved by incorporating them into the entry-content file.

Comment: in what part of the code above do the first ones get called?

Comment: For the categories, the content is after </header>, closing out with the <hr />

Comment: I meant the images - sorry if that wasn't clear. I don't see where they get called in the code.

Comment: My bad - <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> is where that is being called.

Comment: ah, silly me. I see that there.

Comment: try moving `<div class="cat-thumbs align-right"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>` and `<hr>` into the `entry` template.

Comment: Ok, I think that's the file I need to be in but doing it like that caused a bit of a layout nightmare.  I should be able to play around with it & make it work, though.

Comment: @leftside - your answer was correct, I just had to put it in the right place - post it as an answer & I'll mark it accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `<div class="cat-thumbs align-right"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>` and `<hr>` into the entry template.